# How to get property current page on Page PreInit

Tags: c#, reflection

I don't know how use Reflection to get Property on current page when Page PreInt as follow below image

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from `Page`'s metadata `Id` property is overriden from the parent class. So in order to access that property you need to get property from the `BaseType`

```
Page page = sender as Page;
var pageType = page.GetType();
PropertyInfo property = pageType.BaseType.GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
```